# setPreferredContentSize does not work in the today widget in landscape iPhone on iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, xcode6, today-extension

I'm working on Today extension widget in iOS8 using Xcode beta 6.

I set the frame of my widget by `setPreferredContentSize:` in `viewWillAppear:`
It works nicely in all iOS devices except on the landscape iPhones.

On the iPhones in landscape mode, height of widget becomes no more than 166px(in retina iPhone, 332px). And I am trying to set it about 300px.

I understand tall widget might be bad as Apple mentioned in the [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html), but sometimes Calendar app become very tall if there's many schedules.

Since I have no iOS8 iPhone, I've tested only with simulators.
Is it a simulator's bug?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: I too would like to know how to avoid the automatic widget height of 166px in landscape mode.  I've been testing on a device, using autolayout with the storyboard, and have tried setPreferredContentSize in multiple places.

Answer (score 3):

The maximum height of a NC Widget is not documented by Apple.

However, in my experience, the maximum height is strictly the height of the screen minus the controls on the top and bottom.

This has the undesired effect that a widget that fits nicely on an iPad or an iPhone 6 plus may not fit on an iPhone in landscape!

**This is the case on devices as well as the iOS Simulator (as of iOS 8.1.2)**

In an app I'm writing, the NC widget's preferredContentSize.height is always 210 pt. However, in landscape on an iPhone 5, the widget height is capped at 205.5 pt. So UI elements are packed tighter together.

I've seen some NC Widgets which display UITableViews with a fixed number of rows, which works fine on an iPad or portrait iPhone but gets clipped on landscape iPhone.

In cases like this, you may want to optimistically set the preferredContentSize to the height you want, then check the bounds of the widget's view. If the height is smaller than the preferred height, it may be preferable to reduce the amount of content you display.